# how show different icons and links in your navbar based on whether a user is authenticated or not

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-redux

hello i  want to show different icons and links in  navbar based on whether a user is authenticated or not. i used the isAuthenticated state variable but this not work for me
i will you  provide   the specific code i have for user authentication for helping  me to integrate the solution

i want displaying the logout icon in the navbar when the user is authenticated in menu component
navbar :

```
  export default function Navbar({ isAuthenticated, handleLogout }) {
     return (
 
           
     <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/About" className="nav-link">
               About
              </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/Book" className="nav-link">
              Book Table
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div className="user_option">
        {isAuthenticated ? (
     <Link to="/logout" className="user_link" onClick={handleLogout}>
     <i className="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </Link>
    ) : (
      <Link to="/LoginPage" className="user_link">
        <i className="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </Link>
          )}

              <a className="cart_link" href="#">
                <svg
                  version="1.1"
                  id="Capa_1"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                  x="0px"
                  y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 456.029 456.029"
                  style={{ enableBackground: 'new 0 0 456.029 456.029' }}
                  xmlSpace="preserve"
                >
                  
                  
                </svg>
              </a>
              <form className="form-inline">
                <button
                  className="btn my-2 my-sm-0 nav_search-btn"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
              </form>
              <a href="" className="order_online">
                Order Online
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
       const LoginPage = ({ loading, error, ...props }) => {
        const navigate = useNavigate(); 

   const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

   // Check authentication status on component mount
   useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('USER_KEY');
    if (token && token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } else {
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
    }
  }, []);

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        userName: '',
        password: ''
        });

    const handleSubmit=(evt)=>{
        evt.preventDefault();
        props.authenticate();

        userLogin(values).then((response)=>{

            console.log("Response:", response); // Log the entire response object
    if (response.status === 200) {
      props.setUser(response.data);
      navigate('/dashboard');
      props.handleLogin();
      
    } else {
      console.log("Error status:", response.status); // Log the HTTP status code
      console.log("Error data:", response.data); // Log the response data
      console.log("Error status text:", response.statusText); // Log the status text
      props.loginFailure('Something Wrong! Please Try Again');
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error:", err); // Log the error object
    if (err && err.response) {
      switch (err.response.status) {
        case 401:
          console.log("401 status");
          props.loginFailure("Authentication Failed. Bad Credentials");
          break;
        default:
          console.log("Default error status:", err.response.status);
          props.loginFailure('Something Wrong! Please Try Again');
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Error without response:", err);
      props.loginFailure('Something Wrong! Please Try Again');
    }
            

        });
       

        
    }

      const handleChange = (e) => {
          e.persist();
          setValues(values => ({
        ...values,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }));
      };

      const handleSuccessfulLogin = () => {
         // Use navigate('/dashboard') here
         navigate('/dashboard');
      };
    
        console.log('Loading ', loading);

Code App.js:


        function App() {
        const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
         const handleLogin = () => {
  
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
    }

  
     const handleLogout = () => { 
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
    }

     return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          {/* Pass isAuthenticated state to Navbar */}
          <Navbar isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} handleLogout= 
   {handleLogout} />


i  want to show different icons and links in  navbar based on whether a user is authenticated or not. i used the isAuthenticated state variable but this not work for me
i want displaying the logout icon in the navbar when the user is authenticated in menu component
```

Comment: you are missing the end of the code in the login page where you send the isAuthenticated state variable to the navbar

Comment: in App.js i added in the post

Answer (score 0):

First of all looks like your state in the Login Page is different from the state from you use in your App component, so currently your Navbar is always receiving a false value if there's an existing user key in your local storage.

You should have something like this in your Login Page in your useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('USER_KEY');
    if (token && token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      props.handleLogin();
    }
  }, []);
```

Either that or move your use effect to your app component so all your child components are aware of the isAuthenticated state property